# How select records within a radius of two kilometers in the field using SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I need create a query that returns the records in a perimeter of two kilometers in the table I have the field position, formatted 0xE6100000010CCEC1D8E7D644254000B672E522E851C0.

the query does not work well for all points, I must change the perimeter (2000) to view the records, what am I doing wrong??

```
DECLARE @position geography;
SET @position= geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-74.0049539 40.6502672)', 4326);

SELECT restaurantid,Position , Position.ToString() ,@position.STDistance(Position) FROM deliveryconfiguration
WHERE Position.STDistance(@position) IS NOT NULL  AND Position.STDistance(@position) <= 2000;
```

Comment: Are the units for @position kilometers or meters?  If it's meters then 2000 is right.

Comment: Hi...@position= geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-74.0049539 40.6502672)', 4326)